# Intellij IDEA Cucumber plugin doesn't see step definitions if they come from dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have steps defined in another artifact. I inherit from that class in the test/java folder in current project. Plugin shows warning "Undefined step reference" and are unable to highlight or navigate to definition.

The issue is also discribed here:
[IDEA-104610](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104610) Support Cucumber step definitions from other JARs / projects
[IDEA-157652](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157652) Cucumber intellisense lost when placing stepdefinitions in external library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij IDEA (mine is 2018.3.6) actually can resolve and highlight such steps, but only if you have sources jar with step definitions. So solution is to download sources with Maven or another build tool.

I also would like to show how to generate sources jar if you own that dependency with test definitions:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

And if you also generate separate test jar then:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-test-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Hi, This seems this answer doesn't work. I attached source jar and deployed to nexus. In other project added dependency with "maven-dependency-plugin" plugin with <id>download-sources</id> and <goal>sources</source>. When i run test phase i do see MyProjXXXsource.jar downloaded. but My IntelliJ's cucumber plugin is showing missing step definition. Can you please tell how IntelliJ's cucumber plugin is able to select classes from downloaded source jar file by mvn ?